# Module Error: No Module Named 'py.io' Pytest Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

You can get more details [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009046200-No-module-named-py-io-?page=1#community_comment_360001865039).

I just tried to make a simple pytest file. In terminal, everything works fine. However, when I try running it in Pycharm it gives me 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py.io''.[image] I have the pytest package installed. [image] And my default test runner is pytest.[image] I have tried reinstalling Pycharm, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened when the testcase file was in my rust project directory in pycharm.
When I run a testcase in my python project(Django,Scientific..), The testcase running correctly.
I guess the reason is the project settings

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but in my case i needed to remove all "mark as sources root" from all the folders and then it worked.
[image: How to set\exclude directory as source root]

** Photo taken from the internet